# CSS: Is a hidden object clickable?

Tags: css, visibility, display

If the `visibility` property of the style of an HTML element is set to `hidden`, is it still clickable?

When the `display` property is set to `none`, the element is not even part of the DOM tree, so that is not a problem. But I was wondering if a `hidden` element still responds to mouse events.

Comment: It's completely removed from element flow, but I'm not sure if it's taken out of the DOM tree...

Comment: You are not quite right about "display: none". The object with "display: none" is still a part of DOM tree (so you can find it by jQuery, for example), but it is not a part of visual tree.

Comment: If you want have object clickable you can use 'opacity' instead.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

With `display: none` it *is* still part of the DOM. It just isn't rendered in the viewport.

As for clicks on elements with `visibility: hidden`, the events are *not* fired.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/2fsFR/).

```js
$('div').click(function() {
    alert('Hello')
});
```

```css
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    visibility: hidden; 
}
```

```html
<div>abc</div>
```

Comment: Does anyone know whether all browsers are compliant with this? I kind of remember that in very old versions of Firefox `visibility: hidden` elements still fired click events, but maybe I’m confusing this with those elements affecting the layout…

Answer (score 14):

Making div  hidden or display none just makes it un clickable to user.
But in real its still an element in dom and you can click it with another java script/jquery like this.

```
$('div').click(function() {
    alert('Hello')
});
$('div').click();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jinthakur/2fsFR/483/)
[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer.  The marked-answer by @Alex is wrong/misleading.  Why would anyone need this, someone might ask?  I have a Partial-View in an Ajax Form and I want to Asyncronously Update it every X Minutes with a Partial-View Refresh.  I added a Hidden Submit-Button to the Partial-View, and set up a timer to click the Button every X-Minutes and I was golden!  My solution will check to see if any data has changed and then persist them back to the server (think auto-save).

Comment: @MikeTeeVee couldn't you just set an interval and then collect and post the data? seems weird that you have to hide an ui element to click that programmatically

Comment: @idkwhatsgoingon I added `<button name="ActionVerb" value="Resume" data-AsyncPostback_RefreshInterval="@Model.PauseLimit" type="submit" hidden></button>`  From here I had some Javascript that looked for any `"ActionVerb"` buttons (that did not have a Property Style of `"display:none;"`), and it would parse out what Refresh Interval to use, and the Button would post back the Verb I wanted to Process (in this case "Resume", which would trigger a Refresh for me).  This gave me the ability to write the JS once, then drop a Button like this anywhere and have it immediately wired up with a Timer.

Comment: This actually is **not** the correct answer because it talks about display: none, while OP asks about visibility: hidden.

Comment: @TylerH see the fiddle code. I have visibility hidden code.

Comment: @JinThakur You need to put your full answer contents in the answer itself. Why include code in an off-site link that can/will die one day and not in the answer?

Comment: @TylerH it will not die. I have an account with them. fiddle lets you run and test code

Comment: @JinThakur Every site will die eventually; unless you are in charge of it you have no control over when. SO has guidance about links in answers; answers should not rely on links to external sites in order to provide value.

Answer (score 7):

No.

An element such as a hyperlink can't be clicked (and the link followed) if the visibility is set to hidden. Similarly, onclick events won't be fired.

Answer (score 0):

> If the visibility property of the style of an HTML element is set to hidden, is it still clickable?

Only if its children override the visibility.

---

CSS `visibility` does not forcefully apply to all children. Suppose you have a dialog box (my use case) that uses `visibility:hidden`. If anything inside that dialog box uses `visibility:visible` it will "break through" the parent and allow events.

The foolproof way is to create a new stacking context and shrink it to 0. Using `transform` is a simple way without having to cause a layout reflow (eg: `max-height`).

```
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scale(0);
```

```html
<div style="visibility:hidden">
  <input style="visibility:visible" value="Visible child">
</div>

<div style="visibility:hidden;transform:scale(0)">
  <input style="visibility:visible" value="Visible Child">
</div>

<div style="visibility:hidden">
  <input style="visibility:visible;opacity:0" value="Transparent Child">
</div>

<div>
  <input value="Normal">
</div>
```

It'll still take up the same space it normally would, but click events won't trigger, nor will the cursor change. That says nothing about keyboard `Tab` though...

Comment: Possibly a useful comment, but not really an answer to the question--descendants with visibility: visible obviously don't have visibility: hidden on them anymore, because you... just overrode ti with visibility: visible.

Comment: >"visible obviously don't have visibility:hidden" on them. It's not obvious because this doesn't apply to other properties like `display:none`. I updated the answer to more clearly answer the question.

Comment: @TylerH I'm here approximately 6 months later having searched for the effects of  `visiblity:hidden`, following the advice of this very stackoverflow question, and then realizing there was an element about 10 nodes deep that had `visibility:visible` that was taking mouse events. It's not obvious. The example is obvious, as answers should be. But the practice of allowing any child node, regardless of how deep or within shadow roots, to receive events is not obvious because children overriding `visibility` is not obvious.

Comment: @TylerH "That you forgot about it is not a 'gotcha'; just means you didn't keep track of your own styles." That's a blind assumption on your part. *Anything* including externally sourced elements can break visibility. Things you *subjectively* claim to be "obvious" is still included in the spec like https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui/#pointer-events-control (See Notes) noting the subtree. It has been resolved that it should be added to spec https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/6123#issuecomment-893890561 but be sure to let W3C know it's not needed since it's "so obvious" /s