# hovering over a dropdown menu with display: table doesn't work in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I'm doing a dropdown menu similar to bootstrap's. the only difference is that my dropdown-menu's default state is `display: table` because i need the menu to look like a table. unfortunately, this doesn't work in IE10:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LfdoB

It works correctly in safari, chrome, and firefox.

What happens in IE is that the first hover works, but subsequent hovers do not show the dropdown-menu, but i do see the box-shadow. it seems that `height: 0`, though setting `height: auto` doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't know why IE is behaving like that.

Anyway, I get it to work making display:table permanent (that is, in the normal state) and hidding - showing it thru visibility:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: table;
    visibility: hidden;
    min-width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 4px rgba(0, 0,0, .15);
}

:hover > .dropdown-menu {
    visibility: visible; 
}
```

[updated codepen](http://cdpn.io/zdCHK)

Comment: semi-related question, if i use `visibility: hidden`, is it guaranteed that the dropdown menu won't be clickable when hidden?

Comment: the elements with visibility:hidden don't fire mouse events. See [http://stackoverflow.com/q/5659563/1926369]. Or at least, they shouldn't, it's difficult to say it's warranted :-)

Comment: Why IE Why could be one of the most popular phrases :-)