# When changing visibility attribute in mousedown handler, click handler is not triggered in Safari or Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I register a click handler and a mouse down handler on a `<div>` that contains other `<div>`s. By default the inner `<div>` is set to `visibility: hidden`. In the `mousedown` handler the `visibility` is set to `visible`.

The problem is that in Safari and Firefox the click handler does not fire the first time you click on the *outer* `<div>`. In Chrome the click handler fires.

I have made a reduced test case: https://jsbin.com/hequku/edit?html,css,js,output

The interesting thing is, that if instead of manipulating the `visibility` attribute you manipulate the `opacity` attribute, the cross-browser differences go away.

What I am trying to figure out is:

- Is this something that is expected to be different between browsers? If not, what is the spec conforming behavior?
- Am I missing something about what one should and should not be able to do in `click` and `mousedown` handlers?

Comment: Works for me in FF, make sure you fire the binding functions when the DOM is ready and the elements to attach the event handlers on are actually in the DOM when you try to bind those event handlers.

Comment: @Arbel so for you when you use the provided example the click event fires? Can you share version/platform of Firefox that you are using?

Comment: I ran the test on FF 44.0.2/Win 8.1

Answer (score 0):

'visibility: hidden' is meant for content that 'is not yet or no more' relevant.
So I guess browser won't fire click events for content that isn't relevant.
Try using 'display: none' instead.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The reason I was using `visibility: hidden` was that I wanted the layout space to be taken up by the element. Using `display: none` will collapse the layout space, which is not ideal for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

This W3 School link talks about how `visibility:hidden` still takes up space if there. I ran into this before and it has something to do with how some browsers take `hidden` as disabled; hence, why your event won't fire. Using `opacity` is the work around for this.
I believe the event not firing on `visibility:hidden` is the correct response. Also, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659563/css-is-a-hidden-object-clickable) question and answer.