# Toggle style in vanilla

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any native JavaScript function that allow toggling style (not class) on an element?

So far, I'm using this kind of script:

```
target.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    target.classList.toggle('target--is-visible')
}
```

Following by the style:

```
target {
    visibility: hidden;

    &--is-visible {
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

And I'd love being allowed to do so:

```
target.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    target.style.toggle.visibility = 'visible'
}
```

---

---

**EDIT**

*[Ternary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)* is the closest of what I'm looking for in term of readability.

And the function sent by the @GuyWhoKnowsStuff uses ternary operator and deserves to be shared :

```
const div = document.querySelector('div');

function toggleStyle(el, prop, style1, style2) {
  el.style[prop] = el.style[prop] === style1 ? style2 : style1;
}

div.addEventListener('click', e => {
  toggleStyle(div, 'background', 'red', 'blue');
});
```

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: You can try something like `target.style.visibility = target.style.visibility == 'visible' ? 'hidden' : 'visible'` However toggling a css class is cleaner approach

Comment: @Satpal - toggle isn't a style property

Comment: Thanks four your comment @Satpal ! It's the kink of easy way I'm looking for. Why isn't it a cleaner approach? In term of readability or performance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');

function toggleStyle(el, prop, style1, style2) {
  el.style[prop] = el.style[prop] === style1 ? style2 : style1;
}

div.addEventListener('click', e => {
  toggleStyle(div, 'background', 'red', 'blue');
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 40px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>Click Me</div>
```

or in your case, I do not believe click event fires if the `div` visibility is hidden,

see [CSS: Is a hidden object clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659563/css-is-a-hidden-object-clickable),

so instead toggle opacity like so:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');

function toggleStyle(el, prop, style1, style2) {
  el.style[prop] = el.style[prop] === style1 ? style2 : style1;
}

div.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
  toggleStyle(div, 'opacity', '0', '1');
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 40px;
  background: red;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>Click Me</div>
```

Comment: Actually I wasn't looking for toggling visibility on an element, but more for a general good approach to toggling style. Ternary Operator is what is the closest of that, but your custom function could be really useful!
So thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also add a prototype like this:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.toggleVisibility = function()
{
    this.style.visibility = this.style.visibility == 'visible' ? 'hidden' : 'visible'
}
```

and then use like below:

```
target.toggleVisibility();
```

It will make it visible and hidden on each invocation.

Answer (score 2):

You could do with [`ternary operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) for toggle

```
target.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  target.style.visibility = target.style.visibility == 'visible' ? 'hidden' : 'visible'
}
```