# JQuery: How to fire click event on hidden element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, visibility, display

I want to create a flashing effect. When user click the flashing element, it will be disappeared. However, it seems not every "user's click" can fire the "click event". Sometimes, when I clicked the flashing element, it didn't disappear. I thought the reason is **a hidden element can not be clicked**. Just like this article says [CSS: Is a hidden object clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659563/css-is-a-hidden-object-clickable). So, is there other methods to make the flashing element disappeared immediately when user clicks the element?

```js
var flashToggle = setInterval(function() {
  $("div").toggle();
}, 200)

$("div").on("click", function(e) {
  clearInterval(flashToggle);
  $(this).hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Flashing element</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the flashing element inside *another* element, and put the handler on that parent element. Also, you might change the *visibility* property of the flashing element, not the `display` of the flashing element, so that it doesn't change the layout of your page every time it appears or disappears.

```js
const child = $('#child');
let visible = true;
var flashToggle = setInterval(function() {
  visible = !visible;
  child.css('visibility',
    visible
    ? 'visible'
    : 'hidden'
  );
}, 500)

$("#container").on("click", function(e) {
  clearInterval(flashToggle);
  $(this).hide();
})
```

```css
div {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="child">Flashing element</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, hidden/toggle will hide elements by setting the css `display`. When hidden, elements can not receive clicks. You can try the following:

1. Use `.css('visibility','hidden|visible')` instead. This is recommended as it does not have the side effect of changing container size and causing jiggling of other elements.
2. Wrap your flashing element inside a container element, register the click on the container element instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Although method 1 can't work(The visibility: hidden element can not fired click event either), method 2 can remove the flashing element immediately!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use opacity : 0|1 instead of display: none / visibility: hidden.
On click event on opacity: 0 worked for me.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).hide(); ---> $("div").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you're looking for: `$("my-element").click()`

Comment: his question is about this not working on hidden elem if i understand well